# Set initial user and pass for phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

I installed the apache2 server in Debian, using testing version (close to 9), mysql server and phpmyadmin without errors.
Problem is that when attempting to start phpmyadmin it asks for user and pass and I don't know where to set those.
Thank you.

Comment: It's trying to log into the database. Did you set up the root database login during installation? There's instructions on the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/MySql) to reset this.

Comment: Intructions are also in config.inc.php. Basically you need to run dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin, you cannot force password into

Answer (score 0):

by default the username is : root, and there is no password